# How to deduplicate dependencies between multiple bundles?

Tags: webpack

To set the ground:

- I am working on a large website with multiple developers working on multiple modules at once.
- Code for these modules live in separate repositories.
- Modules are bundled separately.
- All of these modules are bundled into scripts using [webpack](/questions/tagged/webpack) and share common dependencies (e.g. [react](/questions/tagged/react)).
- The scripts associated with the modules are loaded separately on the page.

This creates a massive script duplication problem. There are now 5 modules on the page which depend on React ^v15.3.0. Thats 133K x 5 just for the React dependency.

How to deduplicate dependencies between multiple bundles?

I am open to considering higher-level abstractions to the continuous-deployment, bundling, etc. strategy (e.g. use of the monolithic repository pattern, if that would somehow benefit the setup.)

Comment: So each module is bundling it's dependencies into a standalone artifact and then these smaller modules are bundled together?

Comment: Each module is bundling its dependencies into a standalone artefact and this artefact is then requested as a standalone script in a HTML document. This part of the design is open to change. In fact, everything is open to change as long as: each module can have its own dependency tree (e.g. different React versions must be able to coexist between modules.)

Comment: Modules never include their dependencies. Look at something like angular-bootstrap, it does not explicitly contain a version of angular within itself. These dependencies should be included by the application not the individual modules.

Comment: Your suggestion is not going to work because of the constraint I have shared earlier ("each module can have its own dependency tree").

Comment: Perhaps a better example is bootstrap.js does not contain JQuery but tells you which version of JQuery it is comparable with.

Comment: It might help to understand that these modules are included at the ESI level at the moment. We are talking about a truly mega portal (in top 100 in Alexa, just to grasp the scale). Some of the modules are as old 10 years, new modules are being written weekly. I realise that the problem I am describing is fairly unique and will probably require a unique solution. I am researching if there has been anything done in this domain already.

Comment: It is not a suggestion but a simple fact of how modularization works. If you want to be able to mix and match modules without them explicitly including their own dependencies and causing potential version clashes they simple cannot contain their dependencies. Browser modularization is more akin to how dependency management works in Java, via Maven. One and only one version of a library should be loaded, it is up to the application developer to determine what version is compatible with all of the components they are using.